# Which is the main verb, 'are' or 'done'? And what is the other verb?

Tags: verbs

The tasks are to be done by next week.

I see two verbs here, but I cannot tell which one is the main verb. If one is the main verb, then what kind of verb is the other verb? A supporting verb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a comment, John Lawler writes:

The concept "main verb" is useful [only] in grammar schools, where complex sentences are rarely encountered.

The *be to Verb* construction and its passive *be to be Verb-en* construction are complex verb phrases with complex internal relations. The meaning of the construction is modal, indicating future scheduling (which, being future, is hypothetical) either of a person's future actions or of others' actions with regard to them

(e.g, *He is to be hanged in the morning*).

Ask your teacher which verb they consider the "main verb". Nobody else cares but teachers. –
John Lawler

Answer (score 1):

> [*The tasks are* [*to be* [*done by next week*]]].

There are three verbs in your example: two instances of "be", and "do", and thus there are three clauses, as bracketed. Each of the last two clauses is a complement of the verb in the the clause that precedes it.

Each verb could be called a 'main verb', but that just goes to show how meaningless the term 'main' really is. And note that although "be" is an auxiliary verb, it is just as much a 'main verb' as "done" is.

My advice to you is don't use it!